# Parasoft violation EXCEPT.NCSAE-3 on return line

Tags: c#, parasoft

Throughout my codebase, I have a lot of parasoft violations

> **EXCEPT.NCSAE-3**
> Do not "catch" 'Exception', 'SystemException' or 'ApplicationException'.

occurring on the return line of functions. 
Any idea why that might be? Should they just be suppressed? Am I not handling something?

Example:

```
private async Task<int?> GetClientIdAsync(long? userId) {
    List<Client> _clients = await _clientService.GetClientsByUserId(userId.Value);

    if (_clients.Count == 1) { return _clients[0].ClientId; }

    return null;  // This is where the parasoft violation is occurring
}
```

Comment: What version of Parasoft dotTEST do you use? I suppose that it is v.9.x. You may need to upgrade it to get the latest.

Comment: DTP Engine for .NET 10.3.0.426

Comment: You have to use at least 10.3.3.x or the latest one. See changelog, as mentioned rule has been re-implemented in dotTEST v10.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JED, you have to upgrade your Parasoft dotTEST version.Described behavior has been fixed in v10 of dotTEST.